# How to delete a variable inside a function which was created within another function?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on something where I want to delete a dataframe that was sent into a function, from another function where it was created. How do I go about this?

Example:

Function to take a `df` and delete it:

```
def delete_file(df):

    del df
```

Function to create a `df` and send it to my `delete_file()` function:

```
def create_and_delete_file():

    import pandas as pd

    # create / import dataframe
    x = pd.DataFrame({'name':['jon','mary'],
                     'age':[12,45]})

    # send the dataframe to my delete function
    delete_file(x)

    # now print it
    print(x)
```

Let's call the functions. As you can see, I can still print dataframe `x` after I sent it to my `delete_file` function.

```
create_and_delete_file()

   name  age
0   jon   12
1  mary   45
```

How can I delete it?

**edit** More info in red text below (i know there are better ways to analyse a df, this is just hypothetical) The dataframe has 4 cities, equally split. Datafarme is 1GB in size.

```
# dataframe size 1 Gigabyte

def _calculate_city_sales(df):

    '''
    The dataframe 'df' is 1 GB in size
    We will split it into four segments
    Each segment is 250Mb in size
    So at the end of the operation (Berlin)
    has RAM usage not doubled? 
    '''

    NY = df[df['city']=='NY']
    sales = NY.sales.sum()
    print(f'New York Sales: {sales}') # 1GB + 250Mb of RAM in use

    LA = df[df['city']=='LA']
    sales = LA.sales.sum()
    print(f'Los Angeles Sales: {sales}') # 1GB + 250Mb + 250Mb of RAM in use

    HK = df[df['city']=='HK']
    sales = HK.sales.sum()
    print(f'Hong Kong Sales: {sales}') # 1GB + 250Mb + 250Mb + 250Mb of RAM in use

    BL = df[df['city']=='BL']
    sales = BL.sales.sum()
    print(f'Berlin Sales: {sales}') # <----- Ram Usage now at 2GB?
```

Comment: It's already gone. You don't `return` it from the function, so it's garbage collected

Comment: Are you using Spyder by any chance?

Comment: I''m using VSCode

Comment: `create_and_delete_file()` will automatically deallocate the memory used for the DF without you having to delete it, once you leave the function. That is, unless there's some funky IPython stuff going on, but I don't think VSCode does that

Comment: Well I have a long list of operations done to a `df` in a function, creating different segments. I want to delete them once I'm done with them and move onto the next slice of the dataframe. If I don't delete them it will increase RAM usage, won't it?

Comment: No. If you keep applying the function, whatever it had in memory during the operation should be automatically reclaimed at the end of each function call (barring what you return)

Comment: For example in one function `calculate_city_sales(df)`, get a large df with sales info -> create segment with sales in New York only, do operations,-> create segment with sales in Los Angeles, do operations, -> create segment with sales in Hong Kong, do operations, etc etc etc. Eventually I'll have dataframes of 100 cities in memory. I want to delete them once I've calculated what I need to.

Comment: Right, so the DF does not get deleted but all the intermediate steps do. You're not following what I'm trying to say about the automatic garbage collection. Do you actually have an issue where you run out of memory or are you just envisioning it?

Comment: I have edited my question. Just so I can try and understand the concept, i would appreciate if you check it out. does the RAM double if I duplicate information in the original dataframe like that? Or do I need to delete it after every slice to keep ram usage down? I have no problem with RAM, but my colleagues might if i package this and share it.

Comment: @Scool your problem is that you are creating many copies of your original data frame unecessarily. First of all, _why_ are you storing the `NY`, `LA`, `HK` and `BL` variables? They are useless, you could do directly `sales = df[....].sales.sum()` for each city. You'd stick to the 1 GB memory usage thoughout all the code. Second of all, why _manually_ do that anyway? USe `groupby`! `df.groupby('city').sales.sum()` will give you a small `pd.Series` object with all you need. Third, this behavior you are trying to implement is very dangerous even for advanced programmers  - dont do that!

Comment: @rafaelc I'm confused. The names just refer to the same object, it's not a copy in memory

Comment: @roganjosh they are copies ;p That's why if you slice an obj `df2 = df[....]`, and try to modify `df2`, pandas will yield the eternally-annoying `SettingWithCopyWarning ` warning

Comment: @rafaelc you're right. I've just reviewed my own mental model as I scanned the code. Clearing up my comments

Comment: @rafaelc See my comment in the question: "(i know there are better ways to analyse a df, this is just hypothetical)" However in my real dataframe the data is so messed up that I need to separate it out and clean/fix it. For example to find New York data I have to search for Nwe Yark, NowYurk, Ny, NewY, NuYork and then in some cases the city is in the phone column etc. So I do need to separate them out just for my own sanity, then process totals.

Answer (score 0):

Try making df None.

```
def delete_file(df):

     df = None
```

Now if you print df it should say "None". I have no idea why del isn't working though. However, you don't need to delete it manually as python does this on [its own.](https://stackabuse.com/basics-of-memory-management-in-python/)